# variable access through javascript function

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am experiencing an issue with the Google maps api v3. I am trying to scale my Google map to fit its markers but it seems that I can't access some variables in the geocode function.

```
function codeAddress(geocoding, address, shop) {
if (address.length > 0) {
geocoding.geocode({'address': address}, function (results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: results[0].geometry.location,
            icon: createImage("/assets/picto_flag_deepidoo.png"),
            title: address
        });

        //Setting the lng & lat in an attribute field for a further use
        shop.setAttribute('lng', marker.getPosition().lng());
        shop.setAttribute('lat', marker.getPosition().lat());
    }
    else {
        alert("Geolocalisation error : " + status);
    }
});
}
else {
    alert("Error : no address");
}
}

console.log(document.querySelector('#shop0').getAttribute('lng')) //null
setTimeout(function(){console.log(document.querySelector('#shop0').getAttribute('lng'))},3000) //null & setTimeout does not work
```

The issue here is that marker is solely set in geocode(). I tried workarounds as accessing the 'lng' and 'lat' attributes with an external function but they aren't set until the document is fully loaded. (tried with a 3000ms setTimeout and it looks like it is not even taken into account)

How do I access the marker and its properties out of geocode and/or how could I get the lat and lng from attribute fields ?

EDIT :

I've tried several ways and I am currently trying with something like this :

```
function mapBorders(){
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var countMarkers = "#{@shops.count}";
    if (countMarkers > 0) {
      for (var i = 0; i < countMarkers; i++) {
        var latlng = document.querySelector('#shop' + i).getAttribute('lat')+","+document.querySelector('#shop' + i).getAttribute('lng');
        bounds.extend(new google.maps.LatLng (latlng));
      }
    }
    return bounds;
  }

  map.fitBounds(mapBorders());
```

Comment: Put your code that needs access to the marker in a function and call it from inside the geocode callback, passing the marker object.

Comment: Geocoding is asynchronous.  How are you trying to calculate the bounds?  How are you trying to use that bounds?

Comment: @geocodezip, I've adited my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that geocoding is asynchronous. The code that you are executing outside of that function is trying to access that information before it is returned. It needs to wait for the result to be returned from google, which is why it accepts a callback function as an argument. This code is executed after the geocoding response.

You could add that code to the geocode callback.

Edit:

You can also pass in your own function to call, as mentioned in the comments above. Here is some pseudo code which should give you some idea:

```
function codeAddress (geocoding, address, shop, myFunc){
    ...
    geocoding.geocode({'address': address}, function (results, status) {
        ...
        //execute my function once the geocoded results are ready, passing it marker.
        myFunc(marker);
    });
}
```

Then the code calling codeAddress:

```
codeAddress(geocoding, address, shop, function(marker){
    //do some stuff with marker
});
```

myFunc then gets executed once the geocoded results are ready.

Comment: The geocode is a void function and do not return anything

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Geocoder

I'm already using the callback throught `results`

Comment: That's not what I'm saying... Your result is available within the anonymous function that you have passed in: function (results, status). The purpose of that callback is to wait for the results to be ready, so any code that needs to wait for those results should be put within that callback. Another way of doing this would be to follow Felix Kling's advice and pass in your own function as a second callback.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved using a global variable :

`var markers_list = new Array();`

And a function called inside of geocode :

`function createMarkersArray(marker){
    markers_list.push(marker);
    console.log(marker);
}`

The lat and lng are accessible through a simple `markers_list[i].getPosition()`

`bounds.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(markers_list[i].getPosition().lat(), markers_list[i].getPosition().lng()));`

`map.fitBounds(bounds);`

Thanks for your replies.